# How to integrate with Boleto Bancario using Node.js and TypeScript? [Adyen]

Tags: node.js, typescript, adyen

I need to perform an integration with **Node.js** and **TypeScript** for generating bank voucher (boletos bancários), i have two problems:

1. When "boletobancario" is passed as the type of paymentMethod, it is not accepted and expects an Enum, but which of these Enums is the correct one for boleto bancario?
2. As soon as i tried to make a request forcing the typing to any, it returned the following error:

```json
{
  "status": 500,
  "errorCode": "000",
  "message": "Acquirer account 'BoletoBancarioSantander_AdyenTest' is no longer supported",
  "errorType": "internal",
  "pspReference": "XXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Is there no longer support for boleto bancario?

```json
{
  "status": 500,
  "errorCode": "000",
  "message": "Acquirer account 'BoletoBancarioSantander_AdyenTest' is no longer supported",
  "errorType": "internal",
  "pspReference": "XXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Comment: Are you using a UI component (drop-in)? Can you paste the code that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

> When "boletobancario" is passed as the type of paymentMethod, it is not accepted and expects an Enum, but which of these Enums is the correct one for boleto bancario?

According to the [Adyen documentation](https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/boleto-bancario/api-only/#make-payment), it looks like the correct enum is: `boletobancario`, there are also 3 other mandatory parameters you'll need to specify: shopperName, billingAddress & socialSecurityNumber.

Adyen has a fully working integration-example which also supports the BoletoBancario payment method [on Github](https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-node-online-payments/blob/main/checkout-example-advanced/index.js#L92). Ensure that [the payment method](https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/boleto-bancario/web-drop-in/) is enabled in the Customer Area for your MerchantAccount.

> As soon as i tried to make a request forcing the typing to any, it returned the following error:

Check whether you are using the correct MerchantAccount when making the API request?